# Zip like function that iterates over multiple items in lists and returns possibilities

Tags: python

In the following code:

```
a = [["2022"], ["2023"]]
b = [["blue", "red"], ["green", "yellow"]]
c = [["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5", "6", "7"], ["8", "9", "10", "11"], ["12", "13"]]
```

I would like a function that outputs this, but for any number of variables:

```
[
    ["2022", "blue", "1"],
    ["2022", "blue", "2"],
    ["2022", "blue", "3"],
    ["2022", "red", "4"],
    ["2022", "red", "5"],
    ["2022", "red", "6"],
    ["2022", "red", "7"],
    ["2023", "green", "8"],
    ["2023", "green", "9"],
    ["2023", "green", "10"],
    ["2023", "green", "11"],
    ["2023", "yellow", "12"],
    ["2023", "yellow", "13"],
]
```

I have searched for a function to do this with itertools or zip, but haven't found anything yet.

To clarify, my use case for this was to iterate through values of a nested/multi-level dropdown menu (the first dropdown returns options, and each option returns a different dropdown, and so on).

Comment: I would like one that works on any number of lists

Comment: I know itertools.repeat (along with zip) may be useful, but haven't found a way to do it.

Comment: How do you know that the first element of `a` and `b` needs a product with the first _two_ elements of `c`? In your own words, can you describe the logic to arrive at the required output from your given input?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi For each item in the lists, it corresponds to another list (4 items in b, 4 items in c)

Comment: *"4 items in b, 4 items in c"* — well, actually, there's 1 item in `a`, 2 items in `b` and 4 items in `c`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I meant the items the most deep

Comment: what would happen to the output if `a = [["2022"]]`? do you get again all 13 sublists or only 7?

Comment: @cards The existence of a second list in b assumes the existence of two lists in a. If you aren't understanding the logic, know that I originally needed this to get all combinations for items in a nested dropdown (the first dropdown has n items, and each item shows new dropdowns, and so on.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, you join the first argument, to a list of lists with only one element each.

Then for each `sublist` and its index `i` in the next argument, you pick the i-th list of the previous iteration `res[i]` and add to `aux` len(sublist) lists each of one is the `res[i]` with one item from `sublist`.

```py
from itertools import chain

def f(*args):
    res = list(chain.from_iterable([[item] for item in l] for l in args[0]))
    for arg in args[1:]:
        aux = []
        for i, sublist in enumerate(arg):
            aux += [res[i] + [opt] for opt in sublist]
        res = aux
    return res
```

In addition if you want to verify that the arguments passed to the function are correct, you can use this:

```py
def check(*args):
    size = sum(len(l) for l in args[0])
    for arg in args[1:]:
        if len(arg) != size:
            return False
        size = sum(len(l) for l in arg)
    return True
```

Comment: Some explanation of your code would be nice. An answer that actually explains what's going on is so much more useful than an answer that just says "Use this code"

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, sorry, now I will try to add it, I'm not good writing english, but I will try my best.

Comment: by flatting a list with `sum(...,  [])` you introduce a quadratic bottle-neck in the program. use `itertools.chain` as recommended in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

Comment: @cards, thanks for the tip, I will addit to my answer.

Comment: Hey, @RodrigoLlanes, could you license your code under the MIT License?

Comment: @Pexp22, of course, the code of the answer is free open code

Comment: I think that this line `list(chain([item for item in l] for l in args[0]))` is totally nonsense, could you give an example for which `list(chain([item for item in l] for l in args[0])) != args[0]`?

Comment: In your solution you are inferring a particular order on `*args`, what is it? I mean `f(b, a, c)` raises an error, why? I also tried to use the `check` function but I got contradictory results: try `for p in permutations([a, b, c]):try: print('ok', check(*p), '' if f(*p) else '') except: print('fail', check(*p))`

Comment: @cards, the correct line is ```list(chain([[item] for item in l] for l in args[0]))```, for creating alist of sublist, each with only one item from the original sublists of ```arg[0]```, I dont know why someone changed it to ```list(chain([item for item in l] for l in args[0]))```

Comment: @cards, the order should be the same as in the question ```f(a,b,c)```, ordered from the smallest to the greatest.

Comment: about the change: I did it. When you changed from `sum` to `chain`, the `[]` around `item` are wrong, yuo will get smt like `['2022'], 'blue', '1']`. Just check it.

Comment: @cards, sorry, you'r right, I have never used chain before, and I thought it takes a list, but I should use from_iterable. Now is solved, and works fine.

Comment: So the condition for the program is that `len(a)<=len(b)<=len(c)`? Then the `check` function is bugged, see my comment above: with either `c, a, b ` or  `c, b, a` the `check` fails but `f` works and **returns always different results**!! and otherwise it crashes (except for `a b, c`)... Sorry but I cannot imagine a _zip_-function giving different results by interchanging the parameter or even crashes for such reasons. I think you should explain under which conditions a certain result is given

Comment: ...and please fix the line with `list(chain([item for item in l] for l in args[0]))`... is nonsense! first you create nested sublist and then concatenate them... this is the what the **identity** function does! So you don't need even extra imports, just `res = args[0]`

Comment: @cards the condition for the programm to work correctly is the check, in other words: for ```args=[a, b, c, ...]``` ```sum(len(sublist) for sublist in a) == len(b)``` and the same for b and c, for c and d, .... If this condition is satisfied, the programm will work as expected.

Comment: ...and ```list(chain([item for item in l] for l in args[0]))``` is not the correct code, the code is ```list(chain.from_iterable([[item] for item in l] for l in args[0]))```. In this case, it looks like identity ```[["a"], ["b"]] -> [["a"], ["b"]]```, but in other cases, like this ```[["a", "c"], ["b"]] -> [["a"], ["c"], ["b"]]```, you can see what I want with it.

Comment: Thanks for your replies and for your time. [1]  `chain` and `chain.from_iterable` produce the same result but have different signatures so it doesn't matter which one you use as long as you pass the right parameters. [2] I agree that `res = list(...) != args[0]` but, at least in the case with `a, b, c`, it also works.

Comment: [3] my complain is that the function doesn't behave like a _zip_: (A) is sensible to the order of the parameters which could give unpredictable results: `f(a, b, c)`, `f(c, a, b)`, `f(c, b, a)` are totally differents (B) assumes that you know the exact structure of the _*args_. So, assumed, that some lists `r, s, t, u` were given and I want to apply the program: if they do not pass the _check_ what should I do? Instead of a _check_ function there should be a normalization function that proper reorganize the data. These points may depend on the lake details of the question

Comment: @cards, I see your point, and its true, but I dont know how to do a more general function with the exact behaviour requested in the question.

Answer (score 5):

```
def foo(*args):
    arrs = list(args)
    prev = arrs[0]
    
    def bar(arr1, arr2):
        ans = []
        for x, y in zip(arr1, arr2):
            for el in y: 
                ans.append(x + [el])
        return ans
    
    for curr in arrs[1:]:
        ans = bar(prev, curr)
        prev = ans
    
    return ans

foo(a, b, c)
# [['2022', 'blue', '1'],
#  ['2022', 'blue', '2'],
#  ['2022', 'blue', '3'],
#  ['2022', 'red', '4'],
#  ['2022', 'red', '5'],
#  ['2022', 'red', '6'],
#  ['2022', 'red', '7'],
#  ['2023', 'green', '8'],
#  ['2023', 'green', '9'],
#  ['2023', 'green', '10'],
#  ['2023', 'green', '11'],
#  ['2023', 'yellow', '12'],
#  ['2023', 'yellow', '13']]
```

Answer (score 4):

Like d.b's answer, but using `reduce` and list comprehension:

```
from functools import reduce
from pprint import pprint

a = [["2022"], ["2023"]]
b = [["blue", "red"], ["green", "yellow"]]
c = [["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5", "6", "7"], ["8", "9", "10", "11"], ["12", "13"]]

def foo(*args):
    def bar(arr1, arr2):
        return [
            x + [el]
            for x, y in zip(arr1, arr2)
            for el in y
        ]
    return reduce(bar, args)

pprint(foo(a, b, c))
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBBbsMgEEX3nGLEym5ZBNw2aaWexPICO5BaIoAmWI17eZeBNGrVWXwN73@GEXFNH8F3h4jbZjGcwS5@SiG4C8znGDABmuMyGVbMGHH26cepJ8Y0vEPfc7VTig8CStfxYWBjNUa3GC6A50nVP6ExnshqnAufFJ1qVBJVJF2NPlH/TPJCsq/0QP0ridwVlZXLclWWx9nRWLAhNA8aT5f2jUEuYqPGRiNKAVnVzaBCkxb00N8B1RUeoTdu@ANtQLgKWGH28DXH3@P@5Yyj1HrnddLtrfq5TV6Jruc1Gau/2tDmWsAoYGrbbfsG)):

```
[['2022', 'blue', '1'],
 ['2022', 'blue', '2'],
 ['2022', 'blue', '3'],
 ['2022', 'red', '4'],
 ['2022', 'red', '5'],
 ['2022', 'red', '6'],
 ['2022', 'red', '7'],
 ['2023', 'green', '8'],
 ['2023', 'green', '9'],
 ['2023', 'green', '10'],
 ['2023', 'green', '11'],
 ['2023', 'yellow', '12'],
 ['2023', 'yellow', '13']]
```

Answer (score 2):

If possible, I would use a different set of inputs of nested dicts/lists:

```py
options = {
    "2022": {
        "blue": ["1", "2", "3"],
        "red": ["4", "5", "6", "7"],
    },
    "2023": {
        "green": ["8", "9", "10", "11"],
        "yellow": ["12", "13"],
    },
}
```

This makes the tree structure clearer, and would be safer since it's not possible that the list sizes mismatch. Though duplicate keys would no longer be possible.

We can the use recursion with `dict` defining branches and `list` defining leaf nodes.

```py
def iter_options(options, path=()):
    if isinstance(options, dict):
        for key, value in options.items():
            yield from iter_options(value, path + (key,))
    elif isinstance(options, list):
        for key in options:
            yield path + (key,)
    else:
        raise TypeError
```

Usage:

```py
>>> for row in iter_options(options):
...     print(row)
...
('2022', 'blue', '1')
('2022', 'blue', '2')
('2022', 'blue', '3')
('2022', 'red', '4')
('2022', 'red', '5')
('2022', 'red', '6')
('2022', 'red', '7')
('2023', 'green', '8')
('2023', 'green', '9')
('2023', 'green', '10')
('2023', 'green', '11')
('2023', 'yellow', '12')
('2023', 'yellow', '13')
```